# Change image view source based on the value from database in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-lists

In my android application I have a custom *listview* `(ArrayAdapter)`. in its getView() method there is a *TextView* and an *Imageview*, ImageView is for marking and un-marking **favorite**. When the application loads first time it checks in database if its id is available in the **favorite table**, if it there its image changes,
but my problem is it marked favorite for non-favorite item. I am pasting my code below

```
      @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
                if (view == null) {
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
                }
                Item item = ItemList.get(position);
                TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

                ImageView favorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favourite_mark_icon);
                if (mHandler.checkForIDMatchForFav(item)) {
                    favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_marked);
                }
 favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    markFavourite(position, v);
                }
            });

                return view;
            }
```

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are reusing the view, getting the parameter `convertView`, you need to change each view state before generate the new view. Recycling allow you to base your new view on a template (the old view) but you should change it if the content are dynamic

Simply add an else branch, where the favorite `ImageView` is setted to the default non marked icon.

```
if (mHandler.checkForIDMatchForFav(item)) {
    favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_marked);
}else{
    favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_marked);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I note that few mistakes in this code. While recycling your code will break. 
Try the following

```
@Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = convertView;
ViewHolder holder;
                if (view == null) {
holder = new ViewHolder()
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);
holder .title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

               holder. favorite = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.favourite_mark_icon);
view.setTag(holder);
                }else{
holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}
                Item item = ItemList.get(position);

                if (mHandler.checkForIDMatchForFav(item)) {
                    holder.favorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.fav_marked);
                }else{
//set here your image 
}
 holder.favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    markFavourite(position, v);
                }
            });

                return view;
            }

class ViewHolder{
TextView title;
ImageView favorite;
}
```

You must handle else condition for the following .

```
 if (mHandler.checkForIDMatchForFav(item)) {
```